# Low lever hls android player

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, multimedia, mediaextractor

I'm having problems using the class [MediaExtractor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html) on HLS streams.

I have this simple app lousy based on the sample code present [here](https://vec.io/posts/android-hardware-decoding-with-mediacodec); with an [mp4 file](http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4) I have no problems: the media extractor detect the codec and it's possible to draw to the surfaceview surface.

If I switch the same code to an [hls stream](http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8) unfortunately the media extractor class cannot detect the format.

Is there some way to instruct the media extractor to correctly handle this format?

Comment: Have you considered [ExoPlayer?](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

Comment: I need to access the byte[] blobs of the single frames, because I'm integrating a custom decoder implemented in C. Practically, I need to access at the mediacodec level stuff. MediaPlayer hide those detail. Does ExoPlayer expose them? I know it's *based* on them, but, skimming the docs, it seems it hide those low level stuff

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: nope... btw the project failed...